# How to select and apply styling to custom tags

Tags: html, css, ag-grid

I'm trying to change a background color of a single table header, the problem is that there is no unique `id`. There is a unique/costum tag but I can't find a way to select it.

The element looks like this

```html
<div 
  class="ag-grid-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable" 
  role="presentation" 
  unselectable="on" 
  col-id="name" 
  style="width:180px;left500px;"
>
```

If i select

```css
.ag-header-cell.ag-header-cell-sortable {
  background-color: #56CC2B;
}
```

It prints all columns headers. I'd like to select the `col-id="name"` is that even possible? [Here](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php) is the page example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using attribute selector.

```
[col-id="name"]
```

```css
[col-id="name"] { 
     background-color: #56CC2B;
     height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div 
  class="ag-grid-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable" 
  role="presentation" 
  unselectable="on" 
  col-id="name" 
  style="width:180px;left:500px;"
>
```

Here i add hide so that the effect can visible.

Comment: `.ag-header-cell[col-id="party"]` I used them both and got desired effect

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here.

Make sure to separate each style accordingly. The style tag should be written this way:

```
style="width:180px; left:500px;"
```

And to select the two classes in CSS, simply add a coma (,) and a space between the dots, such as:

```
.ag-header-cell,
.ag-header-cell-sortable {
    background-color: #56CC2B;
}
```

Let me know if this is what you where after!